# Bounding the expectation of the difference between empirical vs generalization error

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, mathematical-statistics

Let the (defect) difference between empirical and generalization error be:

$$D[f_S] = I_S[f_S] - I[f_S]$$

where the empirical risk is:

$$I_S[f_S] = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} V(f_S,z_i)$$

where $V(f,z)$ is some loss function and $z_i = (x_i, y_i)$ is some training point (with its label) sampled from its distribution.

Let $f_S$ be the function that was chosen based on looking at the training set $S$.

The generalization error of the $f_S$:

$$I[f_S] = \int_z V(f_S,z)p_z(z) dz$$

We are also assuming that the learning algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ that maps training sets to predictor functions $f \in \mathcal{H}$ is beta-stable (uniform stable). i.e.

$$\forall(S,z) \in \mathcal{Z}^{n+1}, \forall i, \sup_{z' \in \mathcal{Z}} |V(f_S, z') - V(f_{S^{i,z}, z'})| \leq \beta $$

where $S^{i,z}$ is the "old"/original training with the ith training point replaced with new sample/training point $z$. Thus, $f_{S^{i,z}}$ is the predictor trained with this new training data (but the same training algorithm).

I was looking at the lecture slides on [this page](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/fall14/slides/class15/class15_stability.pdf) and was confused about slide 20 (titled Bounding the expectation of the Defect).

In it it has the following equation:

$$\mathbb{E}_S[D[f_S]] = \mathbb{E}_S[I_S[f_S] - I[f_S]]$$
$$ = \mathbb{E}_{(S,z)}[\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1}[ V(f_S, z_i) - V(f_S,z) ]$$

That equality on that slide does not make sense to me nor does the following equality. Does someone understand why they are true?

The slides do have the following explanation for it (which does not make sense to me):

> The second equality follows by the “symmetry” of the expectation: the expected value of a training set on a training point doesn’t
>   change when we “rename” the points.

After that it continues and writes:

$$ = \mathbb{E}_{(S,z)}[\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1}[ V(f_S^{i,z}, z) - V(f_S,z) ]$$

Which I am not 100% sure if I understand why thats valid and the last one must be some argument related to the stability of the learning algorithm...

$$\leq \beta $$

---

Anyway, this is what I have tried to make sense of the slide so far:

First I expanded the RHS of the first equality:

$$ \mathbb{E}_S[D[f_S]] = \mathbb{E}_S[I_S[f_S] - I[f_S]] = \mathbb{E}_{S}[\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1}V(f_S, z_i) - \mathbb{E}_z[V(f_S,z)] ]$$

Then it seems that its just ok to "pull out" the expectation wrt (with respect to) to a single training point wrt to all values the training point could take but I can't see why thats ok. i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}_{S}[ \mathbb{E}_z [ \sum^{n}_{i=1} V(f_S, z_i)] - \mathbb{E}_z[V(f_S,z)] ] = \mathbb{E}_{S}[ \mathbb{E}_z [ \sum^{n}_{i=1} V(f_S, z_i) - V(f_S,z) ] $$

I do understand that $z_i$ is a specific value that we sampled. So its a random variable. However, how does that not break the previous equality that we had already established? Btw, before someone says that its ok because of linearity of expectation, my question would be why is $\mathbb{E}_z$ a valid operator in the first place when taken over $\mathbb{E}_S[I_S[f_S]]$, i.e. shouldn't it change the value of $\mathbb{E}_S[I_S[f_S]]$

I do understand that when we have a sample say $s_i$, then $\mathbb{E}_s[s_i]=\mathbb{E}_s[s]$ because $s_i$ is just the random variable s. However, I cannot see why its the same in this case...or how that kind of argument applies here...

---

Thinking about it some more, this is the only justification I have (which I won't lie, I am not satisfied with it because I am not sure of its correctness).

$$\mathbb{E}_{S}[I_S[f_S]]$$

Is just a "constant". i.e. its the value we expect of the empirical risk using $f_S$ as the predictor function. Thus taking the expectation wrt to a single training point does/changes nothing.

$$\mathbb{E}_{S}[I_S[f_S]] = \mathbb{E}_z\mathbb{E}_{S}[I_S[f_S]]$$

which kind of resolves part of the issue.